# How can I render data from Tally to server application?

Tags: php, laravel, tally

I want to render data from tally to my application and vise versa using tally API. When I am using it locally, it is working fine, but I want a solution that when my application is on server connects to tally.

This is the code that I am using with tally API

```
<?php 
$requestXML ='<ENVELOPE>  
<HEADER>  
<VERSION>1</VERSION>  
<TALLYREQUEST>  EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>  
<TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>  
<ID>  RTSAllVouchers_FilterForVchNoAndVchType</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>  
<DESC>  
  <STATICVARIABLES>  
    <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>  
    <!-- TODO : Specify the VoucherNo -->  
    <RTS_KEY>VCH-INV-1</RTS_KEY>  
    <!-- TODO : Specify the VoucherType here -->  
    <RTS_VOUCHERTYPENAME>Sales</RTS_VOUCHERTYPENAME>  
  </STATICVARIABLES>  
  <TDL>  
    <TDLMESSAGE>  
      <!-- Retrieve all Vouchers for specified VoucherNo and VoucherType -->  
      <COLLECTION NAME="RTSAllVouchers_FilterForVchNoAndVchType" ISINITIALIZE="Yes">  
          <TYPE>Voucher</TYPE>  
          <FETCH>ALLLEDGERENTRIES.*</FETCH>  
          <FETCH>ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.*</FETCH>  
          <FILTER>RTS_FilterForVchNoAndVchType</FILTER>  
      </COLLECTION>  
      <VARIABLE NAME="RTS_KEY">  
        <TYPE> String</TYPE>  
      </VARIABLE>  
      <VARIABLE NAME="RTS_VOUCHERTYPENAME">  
        <TYPE>String</TYPE>  
      </VARIABLE>  
      <SYSTEM TYPE="FORMULAE" NAME="RTS_FilterForVchNoAndVchType">  
        $VoucherNumber = $$String:##RTS_KEY and $VoucherTypeName = $$String:##RTS_VOUCHERTYPENAME
      </SYSTEM>  
    </TDLMESSAGE>  
  </TDL>  
</DESC>  </BODY></ENVELOPE>';  
$server = 'http://localhost:9000/';
$headers = array( "Content-type: text/xml","Content-length:".strlen($requestXML) ,"Connection: close");
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXML);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = curl_exec($ch);if(curl_errno($ch)){
 print curl_error($ch);
echo "  something went wrong..... try later";
}else{
echo " request accepted";
curl_close($ch);
$object = simplexml_load_string($data);print_r($object);
}
?>

$server = 'http://localhost:9000/';
```

This is the port of the tally its working fine in local.

I heard of the "Tally on cloud" that tally provides, can I render my data from my application to tally using that If yes, then how?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. If you want to use your application in the server, then you have to deploy all parts of it there including the tally server which is currently in your local machine. And then you have to access it using the correct URL. Same would be true if you used a cloud version - you'd need the correct URL and credentials to connect. Apart from that, I doubt you would require any changes to your code. I can't quite work out specifically what your difficulty is, apart from maybe not understanding how to deploy your code.

Comment: Tally is in my local how can I deploy whole tally on server?

Comment: Well I don't know what the product is specifically, how it's built or installed, but I would guess that however you installed it locally, you should do the same on the server

Comment: does your tally server have a static IP? In that case you just need to use "http://tallystaticIPhere:tallyport/" usually the port is 9000, but if you have configured differently use that. Do you know the address where you can "ping" the tally server?